# Filter out np.nan values from pytorch 1d tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a 1d tensor looking kinda like this:

```
import numpy as np
import torch

my_list = [0, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 4]
tensor = torch.Tensor(my_list)
```

How do i filter out the nan-values, so it becomes a tensor of size 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.isnan`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.isnan)

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 4]
tensor = torch.Tensor(my_list)

tensor[~torch.isnan(tensor)]
tensor([0., 1., 2., 4.])
```