# Filter out NaN values from a PyTorch N-Dimensional tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, filtering, nan

This question is very similar [to filtering `np.nan` values from pytorch in a -Dimensional tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503138/filter-out-np-nan-values-from-pytorch-1d-tensor). The difference is that I want to apply the same concept to tensors of 2 or higher dimensions.

I have a tensor that looks like this:

```py
import torch

tensor = torch.Tensor(
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan'), float('nan')],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
)
```

```py
>>> tensor.shape
>>> [3, 5]
```

I would like to find the most pythonic / PyTorch way of to filter out (remove) the rows of the tensor which are `nan`. By filtering this `tensor` along the first (`0`th axis) I want to obtain a `filtered_tensor` which looks like this:

```py
>>> print(filtered_tensor)
>>> torch.Tensor(
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
)
>>> filtered_tensor.shape
>>> [2, 5]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use PyTorch's `isnan()` together with `any()` to slice `tensor`'s rows using the obtained boolean mask as follows:

```
filtered_tensor = tensor[~torch.any(tensor.isnan(),dim=1)]
```

Note that this will drop any row that has a `nan` value in it. If you want to drop only rows where all values are `nan` replace `torch.any` with `torch.all`.

For an N-dimensional tensor you could just flatten all the dims apart from the first dim and apply the same procedure as above:

```
#Flatten:
shape = tensor.shape
tensor_reshaped = tensor.reshape(shape[0],-1)
#Drop all rows containing any nan:
tensor_reshaped = tensor_reshaped[~torch.any(tensor_reshaped.isnan(),dim=1)]
#Reshape back:
tensor = tensor_reshaped.reshape(tensor_reshaped.shape[0],*shape[1:])
```

Comment: Beauuutiful. This is precisely what I was looking for. I should have checked that `torch.any()` had a `dim` parameter. Extra points for showing how to do the same thing while flattening!

I will accept this as the answer, but you have a tiny mistake. `Tensor`s don't have a `t.isnan()` function, it's just a top level `torch.isnan(t)` function. If you don't mind, please change that and I'll accept your answer :D.

Comment: A ```Tensor```  does have an ```isnan``` method, check out at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html . That's why the code works perfectly. You are right that it does call ```torch.isnan``` in background.

Comment: You are right! I was using an older version of PyTorch. Thanks again! I've accepted the answer

Comment: The N-dimensional code didn't work for me; start with `tensor = torch.arange(600, dtype=torch.float32).reshape(1, 3, 20, 10)` then `tensor[0, 2, 0, 0] = float('nan')` and the result has shape (0, 3, 20, 10)